# Sharing Mac Snow Leopard directory via NFS

Tags: osx, file-sharing, nfs

I am running a Mac Pro using Snow Leopard (not server).  I would like to share a directory with a linux machine.  I have edited /etc/exports on the Mac to:

```
/Volumes/mstore/home/sdavis -maproot=root -rw
```

When I try to mount this from a linux machine, I get:

```
 sudo mount gale.nci.nih.gov:/Volumes/mstore/home/sdavis /tmp/abc
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting gale.nci.nih.gov:/Volumes/mstore/home/sdavis
```

Also, this is what I get for showmount -e on the Mac:

```
% showmount -e
Exports list on localhost:
%
```

In other words, the mount is not seen, apparently.  Any suggestions?  I have not found much good documentation on sharing via NFS on the Mac, particularly for later OS versions.

Answer (score 6):

Bad form, I know, to answer my own question, but....  I needed a couple more steps, outlined [here](http://www.revolution34.com/2007/12/07/nfs-exports-and-mac-os-x-105-leopard/).  In short, I needed to execute:

```
sudo nfsd update
```

As another detail, I added the client name to the export and removed the "-rw" flag.

Comment: [It’s perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq). If anyone gives you a hard time about this, point them to the [official FAQ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) or to the [community FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463) and [other](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513) [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/2729#2729) threads.